# The union of two subspaces is a subset of the sum

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to show that the union of two subspaces $U$ and $W$ (of some vector space) is a subset of their sum, i.e.
$$ U \cup W \subset U+W.$$

So let $$ v \in U \cup W$$
such that $ v \in U$
we have:
$$ v = v + 0$$
with $ 0 \in W$, where $ 0$ is the null vector ;
so
$ v \in U+W$;
thus the union is a subset of the sum, because the sum contains a generic vector of the union.
Is it right?

Comment: Your title states the opposite. But nevertheless you definitely need to build some intuition! Consider the following case : two different 1 dimensional vector spaces in a 2 dimensional vector space. What is the union of those two spaces and what is the sum? Which of those operations gives rise to a new subspace?

Comment: The union is formed only by the vectors that are contained in the two 1 dimensional vector spaces and it is not a subspace because the sum of two vectors can go out of the union. The sum is formed by the sum of all the vectors that are contained in each subspace and it gives rise to a subspace in this case it has dimension 2.

Comment: yes nice! So if you know this and also see this (draw it) then the solution should be easy for you

Answer (score 0):

$W$ is a subspace, so contains the zero vector in the ambient vector space.  Since $U = U+0$, we have $U = U+0 \subset U+W$.  Similarly, $W = 0+W \subset U+W$.  Consequently, $U \cup W \subset U + W$.